# Dynamically override `equals` and `hashCode` in groovy

Tags: groovy, overriding, equals, hashcode

If I dynamically override `equals` and `hashCode` methods for a class, calling those methods directly calls overridden versions, but using them for set uses non overridden versions. Why is it so and is it still possible to dynamically override those two methods for all usages?

```
class SuperClass {
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    println 'non overridden equals called'
    false
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    println 'non overridden hashCode called'
    1
  }
}

SuperClass.metaClass.equals = { Object other ->
  println 'overridden equals called'
  true
}

SuperClass.metaClass.hashCode = { ->
  println 'overridden hashCode called'
  1
}

def a = new SuperClass()
def b = new SuperClass()

println a.hashCode() // overriden hashCode called
println b.hashCode() // overriden hashCode called
println a.equals(b) // overriden equals called

println([a, b].toSet().size()) // non overriden methods called, returns 2 instead of 1
```

Comment: Where did you override `Set`'s equals() and hashcode() in metaclass?

Comment: Why would I need to override `Set`'s `equals` and `hashcode`?

Comment: Sorry, half read the question :-)

Answer (score 3):

Calling `toSet()` on a `List` [invokes the following code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/acc796fa2e18d8a83b743e6cba058c6230f63c10/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L10138):

```
    Set<T> answer = new HashSet<T>(self.size());
    answer.addAll(self);
    return answer;
```

Now `HashSet` (a Java class) has no concept of the `metaClass`, and so does not see your overloaded `hashCode` and `equals` methods. Therefore you get 2 items in your set.

What you can do is call `unique` on your list first of all:

```
println( [a, b].unique().toSet().size() )
```

As this goes through the invoker so knows about the `metaClass` and should give you a set containing one element.

In practice, I'd avoid changing the `hashCode` method via the metaClass.  As you can see, it's hard to know exactly when it will be handled, and things where it is handled well may not be expecting the hashCode to change from moment to moment.

Comment: So with groovy there is no way to override methods so change will be seen by Java classes?

Comment: Java classes do not know about the `metaClass`, so yes the change will not be seen by the Java code (unless it is looking for it by using the Groovy invoker or checking the metaclass itself)

Comment: There's also a similar problem when it comes to dynamically overriding toString() methods. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2599